# Potential difference for negative value

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electric-circuits, potential-energy, voltage

In an electric circuit, the electrons move from the anode to the cathode. The electrons at the anode have a higher potential energy than at the cathode.

The electric potential difference is $$ V_f - V_i $$ but I don't understand why. The final point definitely has much less energy than the initial point, since the potential energy  decrease as the negative charges get closer to the positive cathode.

Let's say the voltage of the circuit is $12\text{V}$. This means electrons at the anode have a potential energy near 0, but negative, something like -0.001. Then at the final point, since potential energy decreases, it would be -12. (Note that I couldn't say potential energy at the anode is 12, because if that were true, it would mean the far away charges are, the greater their potential energy, which is nonsense, so negative values definitely help in understanding). Then if we plug them into the formula, we get -12-(-0.0001) which can be said to be -12. Why don't I get a positive 12?

Comment: I think you’re confusing electrical potential energy with electrical potential. The electrons lose electrical potential energy going from anode (-) to cathode (+) but gain electrical potential, I.e, $V_{f}\gt V_i$.

Comment: electric potential is the electric potential energy per charge. So it's the same thing as electric potential energy but only per charge. So not sure why they gain electric potential. Can you elaborate ?

Comment: Bob is correct. You are making the mistake by confusing energy $U=qV$ with potential $V$. This confusion is coming, yet again, due to the stupid convention that electrons have negative charge. You should be able to convince yourself that if you do everything carefully, the potential energy of the electron will be decreasing as you expect it to be, even though the potential, the voltage, is increasing. Until we fix the stupid convention mistake, you can think of the electron as if it is a bubble, wanting to rise rather than fall.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent  as electrons go from anode to cathode, its potential energy decreases. We know that electric potential difference is Vb - Va. which is equal to ΔPE/charge. As seen, ΔPE is the potential energy at one point minus potential energy at another point. We're calculating the PE for the electron, hence at the anode it has more than at the cathode. If we're told Voltage(electric potential difference) is 12V, since potential energy decreases, it must be -12 at the cathode.  -12 - 0 = -12. Where exactly am I making the problem here from this example ?

Comment: The voltage is +12V means that you already asserted that the cathode is at potential +12V, relative to anode potential (which you set to 0). The potential energy of the electron when it moves from the anode to the cathode drops from 0 to -12|e|V. This is where the minus sign appears. This is why we have been telling you over and over that you confused voltages with charge*voltages, potentials and potential energies.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent can you describe what +12V means then ? its definately potential energy at location A - potential Energy at location B. Location A has to be at cathode, where B has to be at anode.   how do we get +12 then ?

Comment: By using Volts V you already mean potential and NOT potential ENERGY. Potential and potential energy will only have the same sign if the charge you are talking about is positive. i.e. if you move a proton from anode to cathode, then you have to put in +12eV of energy.

Comment: Finally I get it. Electric potential at cathode is PE/Q which is -12/-1 = 12. I was dividing -12 by 1, but should have divided by -1. Is this correct ? and I believe it's how people decided to name it ? why do we divide it by -1 ? I think it's because to distinguish minus/positive signs since we got 2 different types of charges and it makes our lives easier. Is this all correct ?

Comment: @OmarShekriladze, we divide by -1 because the usual convention is that electrons have a charge of -1eV.  This causes a lot of confusion because of the other convention that current flows from the positive terminal to the negative one.  It would make more sense to have one of those conventions be the other way around, but unfortunately they were both set by Ben Franklin who didn't know the relationship between electrons and current (nor did anyone else at the time).  By the time the relationship was understood, it was too late to change either convention since they were too well established.

Answer (score -1):

> If we say that electric potential difference is $V_f−V_i$ then, I become confused. f and i mean final and initial points.

This is not the usual definition of a potential difference. The potential difference is usually $\Delta V=V_b-V_a$ where $a$ and $b$ are different locations with $a$ being the reference location and sometimes called “ground” even if the circuit is not actually earthed. See [Voltage at Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage).

There is no initial and final voltage, it is the potential difference at two locations.

Regarding the rest, $\Delta E = Q \ \Delta V$ is supposed to be negative when the circuit is converting electrical energy into some other form of energy.

So if a positive charge goes from the positive terminal to the negative terminal then $Q>0$ and $\Delta V< 0$ so $\Delta E<0$. If a negative charge goes from the negative terminal to the positive terminal then $Q<0$ and $\Delta V>0$ so $\Delta E<0$. The nature of the charge carrier is irrelevant.

Comment: I don't get how this answers it.  as electrons go from anode to cathode, its potential energy decreases. We know that electric potential difference is Vb - Va. which is equal to ΔPE/charge. As seen, ΔPE is the potential energy at one point minus potential energy at another point. We're calculating the PE for the electron, hence at the anode it has more than at the cathode. If we're told Voltage is 12V, since potential energy decreases, it must be -12 at the cathode.  -12 - 0 = -12. Where exactly am I making the problem here from this example ?

Comment: @OmarShekriladze sorry, I just don’t know how to state it more clearly than I did